Can you overlay two graphs of filtered versions of the same variable in Power BI?
is it possible in Power BI to overlay one graph on top of another, where each graph is a filtered variable from a single column? Here's a simple example to show what I mean: How could you make two graphs of x vs. year, one for NY and one for CA, using the data below?


